# Kivy class in .py and .kv interaction

Tags: python, class, kivy

I'm not fully grasping how classes in a python file and the kivy language interact. I'm currently modifying the Showcase example of Kivy to increase my understanding.

### File structure

- main.py
- showcase.kv
- data/screens/test.kv

#### main.py

```
class Testy(BoxLayout):
    ttext = 'Bla'
    #other code

class ShowcaseScreen(Screen):
    fullscreen = BooleanProperty(False)

    def add_widget(self, *args):
        if 'content' in self.ids:
            return self.ids.content.add_widget(*args)
        return super(ShowcaseScreen, self).add_widget(*args)


class ShowcaseApp(App):
    #code
```

#### test.kv

```
<Testy>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Label:
        text: root.ttext

ShowcaseScreen:
    name: 'LearnKanji'
    fullscreen: True
    #Some ref to <Testy>
```

### Question

I want to have my code in Testy(), because I'm planning to write a lot of code aimed at what happens in that single screen and I don't want to clutter ShowcaseScreen(), because ShowcaseScreen is also meant for other screens.

To clarify, in test.kv I'm referring to the variable ttext. If I didn't make the class Testy() I would have put it as follows:

```
ShowcaseScreen:
    name: 'LearnKanji'
    fullscreen: True
    BoxLayout:
        text: root.ttext
```

And then in main.py I would need to put

```
class ShowcaseScreen(Screen):
    ttext = 'Bla'
```

However since many screens besides Testy use the class ShowcaseScreen(), putting all the code for all screens in here would make it too much of a mess. Therefore I want the code per screen in a separate class. I think this is a better way for bigger code projects.

So how do I refer to  after calling ShowcaseScreen: in the test.kv file? So that I can put the code meant for Testy in Testy() and keep my files and classes more organized.

#### Follow up question: [Kivy class in .py and .kv interaction 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29978507/kivy-class-in-py-and-kv-interaction-2)

Comment: Could you please rephrase your actual question? I sense there is a good question here, but as it stands I am having trouble understanding it.

Comment: I'm not really clear myself how I want it exactly, so it's hard to formulate properly, but I hope it's more clear with this edit now.

Comment: As a guess, you want to control the elements via code but keep your `kv` as plain and simple as possible? You may want to use `ScreenManager` instead, just define the container screen, and manage the elements with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ScreenManager`. Have a look here, I changed some of your code to provide an example of using the ScreenManager to seperate out the code for each screen into their own classes. If there are problems with this let me know.

**main.py**:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class Testy(Screen):

    ttext = 'Screen 2'
    #other code

class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass

class Manager(ScreenManager):

    testy = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_2 = ObjectProperty(None)


class ShowcaseApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Manager(transition=FadeTransition())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ShowcaseApp().run()
```

**kv file:**

```
<Testy>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: root.ttext
            on_press: root.manager.current = "screen_two"

<ScreenTwo>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Screen 1"
            on_press: root.manager.current = "testy_screen"


<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager

    testy: testy
    screen_2: screen_2

    Testy:
        id: testy
        name: 'testy_screen'
        manager: screen_manager

    ScreenTwo:
        id: screen_2
        name: 'screen_two'
        manager: screen_manager
```

Comment: @NumesSanguis That link you gave takes me right back to this page.. Is there another question?

Comment: This is a good example for how much information I gave and that's why I selected it as the correct answer. The Showcase code is a bit more complicated though and I don't fully understand how it works. That's why I made a new question giving the full code of what I have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29978507/kivy-class-in-py-and-kv-interaction-2 , please take a look and see if you can help me :) *Updated link*